# Problemas com download no CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Na view eu criei este link:

```
<td>
    <?php
        echo anchor("./anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf", 
            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>",
            ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'name' => 'baixar']);
    ?>
</td>
```

De dentro dessa pasta `anexos` existe o arquivo `.pdf`, mas quando clico no link, vai para uma página que diz o seguinte erro:

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

link que a function `anchor` cria: `http://localhost/fideliza/anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf`

eu não quero que ele vá para uma página e sim faça o download do arquivo que está na pasta `anexos`

Answer (score 1):

Se tá retornando o cabeçalho (erro) `404` é porque o link tá quebrado, ou seja, ele não ta achando o arquivo, olhe se o caminho está certo.

Se você não quer ser redirecionado pra outra página na hora de clicar no link, você tem que adicionar o atributo `download` no link, segue exemplo:

```
<td><?php echo anchor("./anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf", "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'name' => 'baixar', 'download' => 'nome_da_imagem']); ?></td>
```

Comment: sim... agora está fazendo download com essa tag, mas dá falha no download, como se o arquivo não existisse, mas ele existe..

Comment: Foi o que eu comentei, o seu link não está apontando pro arquivo corretamente. O link está quebrado. 
Qual o caminho onde está as imagens ?

Comment: http://localhost/fideliza/anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf... a pasta chama anexos e não é uma imagem é um arquivo pdf

Comment: No link, ao invés de abreviar o caminho, coloque o caminho literal e vê se funciona, coloca lá `href="localhost/fideliza/anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf"`

Comment: não funciona ainda... tentei isto: `base_url("anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf")` e nao foi tambem

Comment: Inspeciona o link que você criou e olha pra onde o `href=` tá apontando, tem algum erro lá.

Comment: eu inspecionei: `<a href="http://localhost/fideliza/anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="download" download="download"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></a>`... tá certo o caminho... dentro da pasta do projeto `fideliza` tem oma pasta chamada `anexos`.. tá correto.. e o arquivo tá lá

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>anexos/cartao-confirmacao.pdf" download<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>Baixar</a>
```

Use isto